# Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) connection problem

Tags: php, compiler-errors, connection, warnings

this is my PHP code.

```
    <?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",'',"sensor");
if ($conn)
{
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
    
    $q= "select * from temper";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, $q);
    
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $output[] = $row;
        
    }
    
    echo json_encode($output);
        
    mysqli_close($conn);
    
} else{
    echo "probleme de connexion";
}

?>
```

Someone's : say that Access denied means that the authentication failed. That means there is an invalid username or password combination. For SQL, it's obvious that the user can be root. So please go to your phpMyAdmin and check from the users tab. You may find out the password set on the root account. And usually online databases are always password protected.

I checked the username and the password from the user tab and they say :
username: root
Host name: localhost
password: NO

Comment: can you login to phpMyAdmin without using the password? - if yes, pass null as the third parameter to the `mysqli_connect()` function

Comment: This issue should not even arise: **Never** configure your app to login to the database as root. Root can do anything, so if you have any kind of security issue in the code this just leaves your database open for hackers. Instead create a separate sql account specifically for this app which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.